# Where do I find the libxul.so library for my Linux system?

Tags: linux, installation, shared-libraries, yum

I recently downloaded the 64-bit version of Firefox for my Linux system …

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.mydomain.com 7.3.8-25.26.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

but I don’t seem to be able to run it, getting this bizarre error …

```
[davea@mydevbox firefox]$ ./firefox -V
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/davea/firefox/libxpcom.so:
libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Does anyone know what library I need to install to get “libxul.so”?  I tried “yum install libxml” but that didn’t resolve to anything.

Comment: doing an "internet search" showed this link near the top of the results: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxul.so . See list of possible packages you'll have to install depending on your project (don't install them all). Good luck.

Comment: That link lists "libxul.so" and taht is exactly my question.  How do I install it?  I can't find the right package for yum given my "uname -a" info above.

Answer (score 0):

`yum` has a search facility to identify packages containing specific files:

```
# yum provides '*/libxul.so'

xulrunner-38.0-1.fc21.i686 : XUL Runtime for Gecko Applications
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/xulrunner/libxul.so

xulrunner-38.0-1.fc21.x86_64 : XUL Runtime for Gecko Applications
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/xulrunner/libxul.so

etc...
```

The results (i.e. package names) depend on your Linux distro.

Comment: As "uname -m" returns "x86_64" for me, I tired yoru second option, "sudo yum install xulrunner-38.0-1.fc21.x86_64" but got the error, "No package xulrunner-38.0-1.fc21.x86_64 available."

Comment: Just run `yum install xulrunner` and let `yum` figure out the right version for your system. The version numbers above are applicable to my system (given as an example).